# Why laravel 7 pivot with sync don't working?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

This works well.

```
    if ($request->link) {
        foreach($request->name as $key => $social){
            $stall->socials()->attach($social, ['value' => $request->link[$key] ?? null]);
        }
    }
```

But it does not work.

```
    if ($request->link) {
        foreach($request->name as $key => $social){
            $stall->socials()->sync($social, ['value' => $request->link[$key] ?? null]);
        }
    }
```

Stall.php

```
public function socials()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Social::class)->withPivot('value');
}
```

The problem is that it does not store in the database at all during the update.

Comment: that isn't how `sync` works ... the first argument would be the list of ids to keep synced ... https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships (subsection "Syncing Associations") ... it explains how to sync with additional fields

Comment: how to save with pivot?

Comment: it is in the docs it tells you how to do this, you would have to build an array in a particular way to pass to the first argument of `sync`

Comment: I replaced `sync` to `syncWithPivotValues` but it has an error `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany::syncWithPivotValues()`

Comment: that method doesn't exist in Laravel 7.x ... you have to use `sync` ... also that wouldn't work for you since you need different pivot values for each id being synced

Comment: So why not save?

Comment: because you are not using `sync` correctly and you are doing it in a loop on the same relationship

Comment: I will be grateful . Put the full code in this post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to build your list in a particular way to have set additional fields on the pivot table when syncing. It would be an associative array where the keys are the ids and the value is an associative array where the keys are the fields and the values are the values to set on the pivot fields.

You could use a Collection to create the list in the way you need:

```
if ($request->link) {
    $stall->socials()->sync(collect($request->name)->mapWithKeys(
        fn ($value, $key) => [$value => ['value' => $request->link[$key] ?? null]]
    ));
}
```

If you are not using PHP 8 then you could adjust to a regular anonymous function instead of the short arrow syntax:

```
function ($value, $key) use ($request) { return [$value => ['value' => $request->link[$key] ?? null]]; }
```

[Laravel 7.x Docs - Eloquent - Relationships - Inserting & Updating Related Models - Many To Many Relationships - Syncing Associations](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships) `sync`

[Laravel 7.x Docs - Collections - Available Methods](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-mapwithkeys) `mapWithKeys`

Comment: I has an error https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOyAb.png

Comment: @MahmoudKhosravi check the update, forgot the `use`

Comment: I get this error  again .         https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3Z7V.png

Comment: @MahmoudKhosravi sorry my mistake again, it is late ... it needs to be an associative array (as I even said in the answer *blink blink*)

Comment: How to use `associative array`

Comment: i just updated the answer to use an associative array for the pivot fields

Comment: Only answer this question   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69897376/how-to-update-multiple-group-and-subgroup-in-laravel